# Multiple wives and concubines | male and female "original" intent

Tags: life-of-jesus, genesis, marriage, new-testament, gospel-of-matthew

> Matthew 19:1-6 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 1 When Jesus had finished saying these things, he left Galilee and
>   went into the region of Judea to the other side of the Jordan. 2 Large
>   crowds followed him, and he healed them there.
>
> 3 Some Pharisees came to him to test him. They asked, “Is it lawful
>   for a man to divorce his wife for any and every reason?"
>
> 4 “Haven’t you read,” he replied, “that at the beginning the Creator
>   ‘made them male and female,’[a] 5 and said, ‘For this reason a man
>   will leave his father and mother and be united to his wife, and the
>   two will become one flesh’[b]? 6 So they are no longer two, but one
>   flesh. Therefore what God has joined together, let no one separate.”

When Jesus said “*Haven’t you read, that at the beginning the Creator made them male and female*" I believe he was referring to Genesis 5:2.

> Genesis 5:2
>
> 2 He (God) created them male and female and blessed them. And he named
>   them “Mankind” when they were created.

In regards to the unity of one man and one woman, how did the Pharisees as well as others listening to Jesus *(Matthew 19:2-3)* interoperate what Jesus meant *(Matthew 19:4-6)* when they would have also known that Abraham and King David had **multiple wives** and/or **concubines**?

**NOTE:** I don't want this to be about how Christians view polygamy **today** but rather how did those **listening** think/feel/interperate (through **1st century** "eyes") what Jesus was now saying compared to the "views/actions" of their forefathers. Prior to Jesus referencing **Genesis 5** and clarifying that the unity of male and female was orignially intended for one man and one woman, did those practicing Judaism and those following Jesus recognize a difference in what was once practiced and what is now being said; or did everyone already **know the original intent of male and female**, specifically in terms of how Jesus stated it to be in **Matthew 19**?

Comment: **NOTE:** It is my understanding that both Abraham and David were of the bloodline that would later bring us our Savior, Jesus. This furthers my intrigue. Two prominent individuals that did not concede to what Jesus later stated was the **original** reason for male and female. Perhaps they did not know.?.

Comment: I think Abraham only had one wife, Sarah.

Comment: @Shredder - Abraham had a second wife after Sarah died (and there was the Hagar incident)

Comment: @Shredder In Genesis 25 his second wife is found. **Genesis 25:1** Abraham had taken another wife, whose name was **Keturah**. 2 She bore him Zimran, Jokshan, Medan, Midian, Ishbak and Shuah

Comment: @Shredder same time :–)

Comment: @Shredder It should be noted that Abraham did not have two wives at once as you may also be pointing out. :–)

Comment: The point I see Jesus making is not against polygamy, but against divorce.  If the pharisees had asked "Is it lawful for a man to not get divorced, but get married again anyway?" the outcome may have been quite different.

Comment: @Flimzy I agree that Jesus is making a point against divorce, but within His comments he states *"that at the beginning the Creator made them male and female*" which **may** imply one man and one woman in unity (*"So they are no longer two, but one flesh*" ) combined with Jesus referencing Genesis 5:2 it would seem this was the **original intent**. So my question still would be how did those listening interpret all of what Jesus said while also understanding how their forefathers viewed unity of man and woman (women)?

Comment: @E1Suave: It may imply that, but I suspect that's reading our culture understanding into the text, more than reading from the text it's original meaning. I think, for instance, one could say "God created [bonobos](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2010/02/13/the-most-promiscuous-anim_n_450017.html) male and female", and their naturally promiscuous behavior would cause us to assume the statement is about heterosexuality or some other phenomenon, but not about monogamy.

Comment: @Flimzy I see your point, but I am simply interested in how (at the time early in the 1st century) how those listening felt/understood/interpreted what Jesus said. Actually, in this case, I am hardly interested in how it is viewed through the eyes of our 21st century culture. :–)

Comment: @Flimzy Did those listening recognize there was a difference in what Jesus was now saying, and how their forefathers "viewed" unity of male and female?

Comment: @E1Suave: I think that's a good question.  I think it's just interesting, bordering on odd, to tie the polygamy of David and Abraham into it :)

Comment: @Flimzy I am not meaning to focus on the polygamy as a negative or positive but instead focus on how the crowd would of understood/interpreted what Jesus was saying when he referenced Genesis 5:2 (male and female) considering what we have discussed about their forefathers' views.

Comment: Heh - You'd think "no longer two, but one flesh", if taken literally, might well leave open the possibility for that "one flesh" to take on a spouse.  At which point they would, one assumes, "no longer be two, but one flesh" again.

Comment: @MukeTever: Polygamy by mathematical induction :)

Comment: Could we move this one to BH.SE to determine whether there's anything in the Greek that points to "the beginning" containing 10 or 20 virgins.

Comment: @Shredder, Hagar was also Avraham's wife (Gen. 16:3) while he was married to Sarah.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Ah, right you are. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Flimzy. I don't think anyone would take bonobos as a model for heterosexuality; they are notoriously all bisexual (and seem to use sex pretty much as a greeting, and as a way to calm down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"However, my question is still did the Pharisees as well as the rest of the crowd have any confusion..." - I think they definitely had a confusion in their minds at that moment and didn't right away realize the difference between God's original intent and God's forbearance toward His people already in the fallen state. The following verses show both their confusion (verse 7) and the Savior's pointing out to that difference (verse 8: " because of the hardness of your hearts ... but from the beginning it was not so")

Answer (score 9):

I think the Pharisees understood quite well that their ancestors were not perfect. The fact that they did X does not make X right. The example of David that you bring up is a case in point: He was guilty of adultery and murder. The Bible is unusual in that it holds someone up as a hero at the same time that it freely recounts his character flaws -- sometimes big ones like this. I don't think the Pharisees supposed that murder was okay because David did it, or would have found this in any way confusing.

(Ever notice that most history books and biographies tend to present their heroes as 100% good? Their character flaws are often whitewashed: he was forced into it by circumstances; this was accepted practice at the time, etc. There are exceptions, of course, but I see this a lot. But the Bible goes to rather the opposite extreme, being quite emphatic about its heroes’ sins.)

That said, the Old Testament does seem to at least tolerate polygamy. There are some clues in the OT that indicate that God intended marriage to be monogamous. For example, Gen 2:24 "Therefore a man shall leave his father and mother and be joined to his wife, and they shall become one flesh." Note "wife", singular, not "a man shall be joined to his wives". Etc. But these are subtle enough that one could debate them, and I don't know of anything in the OT that clearly, explicitly mandates monogamy. There are plenty of places where a person's sin is called out, and I don't know of anyplace where polygamy is called out as a sin. I'm interested if anybody else here can point to such a verse.

As Flimzy notes, Jesus was condemning divorce, not polygamy. That doesn't mean polygamy is okay, of course, I'm sure there are lots of sins that the Bible does not record Jesus discussing. But that's not what he was talking about here.

Comment: I know it is difficult to separate what we call polygamy from what King David involved himself with in regards to women. However, my question is still did the  Pharisees as well as the rest of the crowd have any confusion or how would they have been thinking/interpreting (at that time) when they knew God had given David these wives, and Jesus was seemingly saying that one man and one woman as the reason in terms of unity for male and female.

Comment: Did it become apparent to the Pharisees and crowd that there was a difference in what God gave David (or had given David the right to do) and what as Jesus states was God's original original intent for male and female when he referenced Genesis 2

Comment: It seems that God gave David multiple wives. 2 Samuel 12:8 *And I gave thee thy master's house, and thy master's wives into thy bosom, and gave thee the house of Israel and of Judah; and if that had been too little, I would moreover have given unto thee such and such things."*

Comment: That being said I don't wan't this to be about how Christians view polygamy today but rather what did those listening think or feel about this (through their eyes) compared to what Jesus was now saying.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the legal requirement of levirate marriage, which predates the Law of Moses, (see Genesis 38,) would make strict observance of monogamy impossible.

Comment: @Mason Well, only if you assume that the brother is required to marry the widow even if he is already married.

Comment: @E1Suave - "However, my question is still did the Pharisees as well as the rest of the crowd have any confusion..." - I think they definitely had a confusion in their minds at that moment and didn't right away realize the difference between God's original intent and God's forbearance toward His people already in the fallen state. The following verses show both their confusion (verse 7) and the Savior's pointing out to that difference (verse 8: " because of the hardness of your hearts ... but from the beginning it was not so")

Comment: @brilliant I see your point. Ironically when reading verses 7 and 8 my focus **was** on divorce alone, but if I carried the logic of my previous question down through the rest of the verses the answer may be found. I feel kinda of silly. :–( Thanks for the help. (Perhaps you would like points for an answer?.)

Comment: "Perhaps you would like points for an answer?" - Yes, I will put it as an answer. I kind of didn't expect that it would help. Well, I am glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus is speaking of the children involved.  One flesh is the offspring of the man and woman and the resulting family it creates.  He is admonishing them not to separate the family.  He goes on to say that this is not for eunuchs because they do not have children.  This pericope ends with the little children coming unto Jesus.

Comment: Please cite sources for this view and address the concubine angle.